# copy columns from one excel to other and run the macro from python

Tags: python, vba, excel

I am trying to copy all the columns from consolidated file to summary file and run a excel macro from python, summary file have columns from A to BB, and i want to copy only upto AI, I tried the below code but its not giving me any result

```
wbpath = 'C:\\Users\\Summary.xlsb'
excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")

workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(wbpath)


strcode = \
    '''
    Sub MacroCopy()
     '
     ' MacroCopy Macro
     '

     '
     Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

     Set sColumn = Workbooks("C:\\Users\\Consolidated.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns("A:AI")
     Set tColumn = Workbooks("C:\\Users\\Summary.xlsb").Worksheets(2).Columns("A2")

     sColumn.Copy Destination:=tColumn


 End Sub
'''
excelModule = workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
excelModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(strcode.strip())
excel.Workbooks(1).Close(SaveChanges=1)
excel.Application.Quit()
```

when i ran the macro in the excel sheet its giving me subscript out of range error. Please let me know where i am going wrong

Comment: Which line of the VBA errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of errors in your VBA code. First of all

```
Set tColumn = Workbooks("C:\\Users\\Summary.xlsb").Worksheets(2).Columns("A2")
```

is not valid because `A2` is a cell reference, not a column reference. But you can't copy the whole of a column from one sheet into row 2 of another sheet, because there aren't enough rows on the destination sheet. You can do one of the following:

```
Set sColumn = Workbooks("C:\\Users\\Consolidated.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns("A:AI")
Set tColumn = Workbooks("C:\\Users\\Summary.xlsb").Worksheets(2).Range("A1")
sColumn.Copy Destination:=tColumn
```

which will paste the whole of columns `A:AI` of the source sheet into the corresponding columns of the destination sheet, or:

```
 Set sColumn = Workbooks("C:\\Users\\Consolidated.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("A1:AI1048575")
 Set tColumn = Workbooks("C:\\Users\\Summary.xlsb").Worksheets(2).Range("A2")
 sColumn.Copy Destination:=tColumn
```

which will copy the largest range from the source sheet that will actually fit when pasted to row 2 of the destination - since an Excel 2007 or later worksheet has a maximum of 1048576 rows.

Finally your `DIM` statement defines variables called `sourceColumn` and `targetColumn` but your code uses different variables that you haven't declared. If you aren't using `Option Explicit`, which is usually recommended but I guess can be ignored for a small throwaway macro like this, you don't need to `DIM` the variables.